# How to use eval() properly to parse Invalid Json

Tags: javascript, json, eval

I have an invalid Json string that I need to parse to an object and feed to a viewmodel:

```
var s = "{ a: new Date(1400000000000) }"; // from a server, can't change this
eval("var b = " + s);                     // parse it to a var b
var vm = new viewmodel(b);                // pass var b to the viewmodel
```

This works, but I end up with an intermediate object b before I can use the parsed object

So I tried:

```
var s = "{ a: new Date(1400000000000) }"; // from a server, can't change this
var vm = new viewmodel(eval(s));          // parse the object and pass to viewmodel
```

but that doesn't work

Can you explain why?

Is there another way to do this without the need for an intermediate var b?

Comment: eval() will not return anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the object expression (it's not a valid statement alone):

```
var s = "{ a: 3, b: 7 }";
var obj = eval('(' + s + ')');
```

Needless to say that eval is not secure, but if you have no choice... Just be aware that this will execute any code the server sends to you. c.f. [Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) for a more thorough discussion on the matter

---

*Extra fun:* try entering both `{ a: 3, b: 7 }` and `({ a: 3, b: 7 })` in the online esprima parser :) http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html

Answer (score 4):

Try to use in this way

```
var vm = new viewmodel(eval('(' + s + ')'));
```

Comment: Your answer is, of course, correct as well, but I decided to accept Aegis' because of his explanation

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is:

```
var s = "{ a: new Date(1400000000000) }";
var vm = new viewmodel(new Function('return ' + s).call());
```

The difference between using `eval` is that this way the code (`s`) **cannot access local variables because the code runs in a separate function scope**.

Comment: I am curious; what would be the performance cost of wrapping the whole thing in a function instead of a StatementExpression?

Comment: Did not mean to downvote this. I can't change my vote now since 10 hours has elapsed. I prefer this approach to the dreaded 'eval' and sure would like to upvote it.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to parse JSON is to use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON). `eval()` is not very secure.

```
var vm = new viewmodel(JSON.parse(s));
```

Comment: Their string `s` isn't valid JSON, as stated in the question, so `JSON.parse()` will be expected to fail.